# how to test if a function has been called that isn't passed as props from another component?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

How do i test if a function that isn't being passed as props has been called with jest/RTL?

```
function CreateForm() {

  const submitHandler = () => {
    //do something
  }

  return(
    <button onClick={submitHandler}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can't, but you also shouldn't, instead it's better to test if it has done whatever it's supposed to do, which would either be calling a callback (passed as prop), calling an external function, or changing how the component is rendered

Comment: What is your `submitHandler` is doing ?

Comment: @SarunUK i guess returning some jsx to display?

Comment: @Teneff i just did a little bit of reading, wouldnt jestSpyOn be able to look into the functins of my code?

Comment: Nope, as it's a variable within a function. And even if it did, the test would've just add false sense of security :)

Comment: ok. Assume that the submit handler is updating the local state value and you are using the same value in the template, In that case, you can check the value of the template to verify the handler behavior.

Comment: @SarunUK so you mean, instead of checking for the process, i should check for the result?

Comment: yeah..absolutely.. You can't mock the private methods. I can provide an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach,

Assume the submit handler is updating the state like below,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CreateForm() {

  const [isSubmit, setSubmit] = useState(false);

  const submitHandler = () => {
    setSubmit(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span class='status'>{isSubmit ? 'Submitted' : 'Not Submitted'}</span>
      <button id="submit-btn" onClick={submitHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateForm;
```

Check the state value before and after the `submission`.

**Test file:-**

```
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import CreateForm from "./form";

describe("Create Form  Component", () => {

  it("should update the state on click of submit button", () => {
    const {container} = render(<CreateForm />);

    const status = container.querySelector('.status');
    expect(status.textContent).toEqual('Not Submitted'); //Before Submission

    const button = container.querySelector('#submit-btn'); 
    fireEvent.click(button); //Submit button click

    expect(status.textContent).toEqual('Submitted'); //After Submission
  });
});
```